# Suggestions on how to improve click-bot performance

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, bots

I'm working on a bot that plays a simple flash game requiring the player to click on multiple fast-moving targets, specifically this:

[image: Click me!]

My current algorithm is fairly simple:

1. Capture an image of the screen
2. Loop through pixels in the screen image and compare their RGB values with the known RGB value of the target image
3. Return coordinates where a match is found
4. Move mouse pointer to coordinates and click

The code for the search algorithm is as follows:

```
    public Point findImg(BufferedImage img) {
        screen = bot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle); // Image of screen
        int target = 2424318; // RGB value to look for
        int rgb;

        // Approximate boundaries (400,200) and (1000,700) of the flash game were           
        // hardcoded in
        for (int i = 400; i < 1000; i += 5) {
            for (int j = 200; j < 700; j += 5) {
                rgb = -(screen.getRGB(i, j));
                if (rgb == target) { // Target found
                    return new Point(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Currently the bot is able to hit about 75% of the targets.  However, it regularly fails to hit the faster-moving targets and will essentially "chase" them across the screen.  I'm assuming it's because my algorithm isn't able to find them fast enough. I've tried increasing the pixel step size but it didn't seem to have a noticeable effect.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For better reliability, you should decrease the pixel step size, not increase it. At the expense of running time.

Comment: Do the targets move predictably in straight lines? What happens if you miss? Can you scattergun clicks around your found point? Maybe you could do what you do now, but if you miss then take another screenshot and work out where the target will be when you want to click it!

Comment: The targets move in arbitrary directions, there is no penalty for missing (you can click as many times as you want), and I am already calling findImage every 125ms to update the screen image and check for targets. Your shotgun approach sounds like a good idea though, I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, use the maximum step that you can: this is the size of the largest uniform square inscribed in the target shape (inside the central disk). You will make sure that the target cannot be missed.

If this is not enough to allow you to click on time, there are two measures you can take:

1) reduce the search area by taking into account the maximum target speed and search around the previous location;

2) predict where to click by estimating the speed and direction of the target (assuming they remain constant); you do this by comparing the target location on successive frames.

These two strategies can be combined, but be sure to master the time parameter: the faster the search will be, the smaller the displacement correction based on the speed estimate. You will need to predict the time the search takes to estimate the displacement.

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to account for the latency in the system (which is something human players do almost automatically).  The flash game probably evaluates clicks the frame after they are received.  Double-buffering and vsync both add latency.  All of that needs to finish before the screen capture can grab an image.

To hit faster-moving targets, you will need to do some tracking.  If you can figure out where your *miss* is, you will know how far behind the target it is.  Otherwise, perhaps your code can recognize when successive misses are near each other, and take longer and longer steps until you hit something.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious that you cannot "catch" the faster moving targets, because by the time your two for loops finish processing that huge screen, the target has moved elsewhere, so your clicks will definitely keep "following" the faster targets. Instead, establish "target-hitting zones" if possible. Let's say you hit targets only in the central portion of the screen. That way, you can reduce the number of comparisons significantly. You could also have multiple target hitting zones. It depends on where these targets originate. If they come, for instance, from the sides of the screen, then it makes more sense to have the target hitting zones over there.

[image]

Also, if you do not get a "penalty" for multiple mouse clicks, then it is better to click in many different places around the matching pixel. So if you find that (450,500) is a match, then it makes sense to click on (450,500), (455,500), (445,500), (450,505), (450,495), and so on, depending on the diameter of the target (i.e. how many pixels wide it is) and also how far your current clicks are lagging behind the target.

Hope this helps.

[image]